# Docker workflow

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose

I am developing a small social-media project using nodejs, postgresql and nginx on a backend.

Locally, I worked with Docker as a replacement for a Vagrant, I have all entities split between separate containers and combined them via docker-compose.

I do not have production experience with Docker. How should I pack result of docker-compose, and deploy?

Comment: Where do you normally deploy your projects?

Comment: For this project I have EC2 AWS

Answer (score 2):

You can build and publish the individual docker images, and do the same `docker-compose` on your production servers. Of course, the servers have to be logged into the registry if it is a private one.

Sample:

```
version: '2'
services:
  application1:
    image: your.docker.registry/image-application1

  application2:
    image: your.docker.registry/image-application2
    depends_on:
      - application1
```

The images can be built and pushed to a [registry](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry) as part of your regular build process.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to modifiy containers to make them production ready, other than [what is described here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/). What you need to do is ensure you are deploying them to a High Availability system that can respond to failures by respawning processes. Here are some examples:

- [Amazon Elastic Container Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs)
- [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/)
- [Google Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/)
- [Weave](https://www.weave.works/)